# Скрыть не заполненные табы в woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, woocommerce

Как сделать так, чтобы пустые табы на странице продукта типа "описание" не выводились? http://prntscr.com/9p7cf6

```
 if ( !empty( $tabs ) ) : ?> //не пашет
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab">
                    <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
            <div class="panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

код в tabs.php не работает

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался?